# Altering a Clonezilla Image

Tags: windows-7, disk-image, clonezilla

I've got a clonezilla image that I need to change out two license keys in. Is it possible to boot from the image and run off it to make changes? It's an image of Windows 7.

Comment: Clonezilla images cannot be booted from.  You will need to restore the image, boot to the disk, make the changem, and recreate the image.

Comment: @Joseph: You can [loopback mount Clonezilla images](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=872832) to view/extract files, so perhaps modifying the files inside is possible too.

Answer (score 1):

From https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound

Clonezilla images cannot be booted from. You will need to restore the image, boot to the disk, make the changes, and recreate the image.

Comment: not necessarily need to boot, but at-minimum you'll need to mount it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make bootable image from clonezilla files with

```
cat sda1.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.* | gzip -d -c | partclone.restore -C -s - -o sda1.img
```

If you have used not gzip compression, change accordingly. You cat chane compression format with file command.

The bad thing is I don't know how to get it back to Clonezilla format for sure.