# Can a Clonezilla image be edited?

Tags: disk-image, clonezilla

I have generated a [Clonezilla](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/) image file of three partitions, but now would like to delete one file from a partition of that image. Is it practical to talk about doing so, in Linux or Windows?

https://sourceforge.net/p/clonezilla/discussion/search/?q=edit+image&limit=250 turned up nothing there, and the solution suggested in  [Altering a Clonezilla Image](https://superuser.com/questions/595555/altering-a-clonezilla-image) is not applicable to removing a file.

Comment: why s that solution not applicable?

Comment: @Jasen The answers discuss making a Clonezilla image bootable, not removing a file, which is my objective.